# Square multi-party transactions via W3C Web Payments API

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps, square

Square provide [multi-party transaction](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/transactions/overview#mpt-overview) payment functionality to their merchants/customers via a native bespoke API. Is there anyway other than this [feature request](https://github.com/w3c/payment-handler/issues/335) to surface the functionality via the [Web Payments API](https://www.w3.org/TR/payment-request/)?

Comment: Could you please explain what you're trying to build with multi-party transactions?

Comment: Please see the "feature request" link. (And also Squre docs on why they introduced multi-part transactions) Basically Web App commission.

Comment: I'm still not following what you're actually trying to do. Square's multi-party transactions are intended on monetizing an app (from a developer's perspective - ie taking a fee out of a payment), which doesn't sound like it's related to the conversation, but please let me know if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking for. And in the absence of an existing mechanism I have proposed a disbursement facility via the PaymentRequest API. PayPal and Stripe also provide similar functionality. Please click the "Feature Request" link above for complete details.

Comment: I had a question mislabeled spam for using words like "monetize" and a "Cha-Ching" picture but @sjosey hit the nail on the head. See: - https://github.com/w3c/payment-handler/issues/335#issuecomment-488181396 for the quote "I must not be articulating the brilliance of this feature because it will revolutionize web payments and most importantly provide a way for PWA vendors to monetize the App!"

Comment: Thanks for the information. So, just to confirm, if you're asking for the "Feature Request" to be implemented into the Payment Request API, then Square has no control over that. If you're asking to divide payments on the payment form, that is not how Square's multi-party transactions work. We handle the multi-party transactions at the time `Charge` is called.

Comment: Yes the W3C API has to support it but then Square et all have to implement the hooks to existing functionality. And no, the user will not see the break down this is done at charge time. As per my suggested solution. Sounds good yes?

Comment: Curious as to why you would want the user to see the break down? Multiparty transactions doesn't affect the end-customer, it only affects the merchant. Ie if a customer is paying $10, they won't be charged more for a multiparty transaction, the merchant would just receive less money. As a merchant you can see this break down in your Square dashboard.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I agree with you 100%. The user does NOT see the breakdown. only the Payment Manager and the PWA owner know of the split.

Answer (score 0):

@adrianhopebailie has detailed a solution right [here](https://github.com/w3c/payment-handler/issues/335#issuecomment-492603458) right now for Web Payment Disbursement functionality that requires no (absolutely ZERO) changes to the Payment Request OR Payment Handler APIs and W3C standards! (Always a bonus :-)

As he correctly points out, the methodData argument is opaque and pretty much down to the autonomous Payment Handler to specify. So Stripe, Square, and PayPal are free to specify to their customers the format/naming-convention for communicating Application Fees between Web App supplier and Stripe.

To quote Adrian's example: -

```
const methodData = [
  {
    supportedMethods: "https://square.com/",
    data: {
      parties: [{ 
        merchantId: "super-mini-cabs",
        portion: 0.1
      },{ 
        merchantId: "driver-fred",
        portion: 0.9
      }],
    },
  },
  {
    supportedMethods: "https://stripe.com",
    data: {
      application_fee_amount: 1.00,
    },
  },
  {
    supportedMethods: "https://paypal.com",
    data: {
      payouts: [{ 
        paypalId: 12478764,
        amount: 1.00
      },{ 
        paypalId: 23448764,
        amount: 9.00
      }],
    },
  },
];
```

Just tell us Square what you need us to tell you and it's done!